# Weighted Set Cover in practice, beyond the greedy algorithm

Tags: linear-programming, approximation

According to the [wikipedia page for Set Cover](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_cover_problem#Inapproximability_results), the greedy algorithm for weighted set cover achieves the polynomial-time approximation bound. There are other techniques for solving Set Cover, [such as randomized rounding of a linear programming relaxation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Randomized_rounding#Lemma_(approximation_guarantee_for_rounding_scheme)), which I believe achieve the same asymptotic bound.

Is there information comparing these asymptotically-equivalently-performing algorithms in practice?